# Name for real that requires infinite bits to specify?

Tags: real-numbers, kolmogorov-complexity

Kolmogorov complexity defines the complexity of things in terms of how many bits it takes to specify them.

All integers can be specified using a finite number of bits, proportional to their logarithm.

Similarly all rationals can be described using finite bits of precision, by describing their numerator and denominator.

All algebraic numbers can be too, by describing the polynomial they are the root of, and then assigning an order to all the roots, and indicating their index in that order.

Even transcendental numbers like `pi` and `e` can be described using a finite number of bits, whether by describing their definition, or e.g. the Taylor series that generates them.

But only a countably infinite number of reals can be described using a finite number of bits (no matter in which language). There's uncountably infinite reals, so most reals cannot be described in a finite number of bits at all.

Is there a name for such reals?

Comment: I suspect you're looking for the notion of a **[non-computable real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number)**. Basically, these are real numbers for which no single Turing machine can determine each of their digits. Note, however, that there are non-computable reals which are still "finitely describable" in a looser sense (e.g. Chaitin's constant), so this is an area where you definitely have to be very precise about what you mean.

Comment: Non-computable is slightly different than non-definable. You can describe a real number as the infimum of a set of real numbers without being able to compute. @NoahSchweber

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but since the OP specifically talked about Kolmogorov complexity in the context of specifying numbers, I think they may be interested in this narrower notion.

Comment: I'm interested in them both, so thanks!

Comment: In particular I'm wondering whether somolonoff induction implies the fundamental physical constants are computable - it seems to me like it does.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's [(un)defineable number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number), as I found out after using different search terms 2 minutes after I asked this.

Comment: Note that this isn't a single notion: "Different choices of a formal language or its interpretation give rise to different notions of definability." For example, noncomputable reals constitute one notion of nondefinable reals, which I suspect is in line with what you're looking for, but there are many others - both narrower (e.g. ruling out transcendentals) and looser (e.g. allowing Chaitin's constant).